# How can I condense the following 3 queries into one?

Tags: mysql

How can I condense the following 3 queries into one?

```
select count(*) as fs1 from feedback WHERE feedbackStatus = 1
select count(*) as fs2 from feedback WHERE feedbackStatus = 2
select count(*) as fs3 from feedback WHERE feedbackStatus = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a Query like this:

```
select
  sum(feedbackStatus = 1) as fs1,
  sum(feedbackStatus = 2) as fs2,
  sum(feedbackStatus = 3) as fs3
 from feedback;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(*) as count_status, feedbackStatus
from feedback
where feedbackStatus in (1, 2, 3)
group by feedbackStatus
```